# Compute the least possible value of $b_{20}+a_{14}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> The arithmetic sequences $a_1, a_2, a_3, . . . , a_{20}$ and $b_1, b_2, b_3, . . . , b_{20}$ consist of $40$ distinct positive integers, and $a_{20} + b_{14} = 1000$. Compute the least possible value for $b_{20} + a_{14}.$

I can see that $a_{20} + b_{14} = (a_1+19d_1)+(b_1+13d_2) = 1000$, but how do I use that to find the least possible value of $b_{20} + a_{14} = (a_1+13d_1)+(b_1+19d_2)$?

Comment: Perhaps you could write down also the expression you are trying to minimise?

Comment: Can $d_1,d_2$ be negative?

Comment: If the sequences still have positive terms then yes.

Comment: Taking the sequences ending with $...999,883,667,501,335,169,3$ and $...7,6,5,4,3,2,1$  you can get $a_{14}+b_{20}=10$. I don't know yet if can be done better.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comment the minimum $a_{14}+b_{20}$ is less or equal than $10$. However 
$$1000-(a_{14}+b_{20})=a_{20}+b_{14}-(a_{14}+b_{20})=6d_2-6d_1=6(d_2-d_1)$$
so 
$$1000-(a_{14}+b_{20})$$
 has to be a multiple of $6$. Now we notice that $a_{14}\ge7$ and so $a_{14}+b_{20}\ge8$, because $b_{20}>0$. Now $1000-8$ and $1000-9$ are not divisible by $6$, so the minimum is indeed $10$.

Comment: Why is it true that $a_{14} \geq 7$ and $a_{14}+b_{20} \geq 8$?

Comment: Since the integers must be different, then $a_i$ must be striclty increasing or decreasing. Suppose it's increasing ($d_1\ge1$), then $a_{14}= a_1+13d_1\ge 14$; suppose it's decreasing ($d_1\le-1$), then $a_{14}+6d_1=a_{20}>0$, so $a_{14}\ge7$